# Mean and Standard Deviation of a column, ignoring zero values - Matlab

Tags: matlab, mean, standard-deviation

I am trying to find the mean of a column however I am having trouble getting an output for a function I created. My code is below, I cannot see what mistake I have made.

```
for j=1:48;
    C_f2 = V(V(:,3) == j,:);
    C_f2(C_f2==0)=NaN;
    m=mean(C_f2(:,4));
    s=std(C_f2(:,4));
    row=[j,m,s];
    s1=[s1;row];    
end
```

I have checked the matrix, C_f2 and that is full of values so should not be returning NaN. However my output for the matrix s1 is

```
1  NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN
3  NaN NaN
.  ... ...
48 NaN NaN
```

Can anyone see my issue? Help would me much appreciated!

The matrix C_f2 looks like,

```
1 185 01 5003
1 185 02 5009
. ... .. ....
1 259 48 5001
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue with the given example code and data. Use the [debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to walk through your code and see what is happening for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

On line 3 you set all values which are zero to NaN. The `mean` function will return NaN as mean if any element is NaN. If you want to ignore the NaN values, you have to use the [`nanmean`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html) function, which comes with the Statistics toolbox. See the following example:

```
a = [1 NaN 2 3];

mean(a)
ans = 
    NaN

nanmean(a)
ans = 
    2
```

If you don't have the Statistics toolbox, you can exclude NaN elements with logical indexing

```
mean(a(~isnan(a)))
ans = 
    2
```

or it is possibly the easiest, if you directly exlude all elements which are zero instead of replacing them by NaN.

```
mean(a(a~=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line `C_f2(C_f2==0)=NaN;` will put NaNs into C_f2.  Then, your `mean` and `std` operations will see those NaNs and output NaNs themselves.

To have the `mean` and `std` ignore NaN, you need to use the alternate version `nanmean` and `nanstd`.

These are part of a toolbox, however, so you might not have them if you just have the base Matlab installation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set it to NaN, any NaN involved computation without additional rules will return NaN,

use find to correctly index the none zero part of your column

say column n is your input

```
N = n(find(n~=0))
```

now do your Mu calculation

Answer (score 0):

To compute the mean and standard deviation of each column excluding zeros:

```
A = [1 2;
     3 0;
     4 5;
     6 7;
     0 0]; %// example data
den = sum(A~=0); %// number of nonzero values in each column
mean_nz = bsxfun(@rdivide, sum(A), den);
mean2_nz = bsxfun(@rdivide, sum(A.^2), den);
std_nz = sqrt(bsxfun(@times, mean2_nz-mean_nz.^2, den./(den-1)));
```

The results for the example are

```
mean_nz =
    3.5000    4.6667

std_nz =
    2.0817    2.5166
```

The above uses the ["corrected" definition of standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Uncorrected_sample_standard_deviation) (which divides by *n*-1, where *n* is the number of values). If you want the "uncorrected" version (i.e. divide by *n*):

```
std_nz = sqrt(mean2_nz-mean_nz.^2);
```